# Not getting uploaded pictures on wordpress site hosted on AWS , when i restarting my ec2 instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I hosted a word press site on my AWS environment using ec2 and RDS(MySQL) instances.
I stopped my ec2 instance, but when i restarted it, the images are not showing and also its taking a long time to load the content of word press too.

This happened earlier also but that time i thought might be due to latency issue, but its happening again and again.

I tried to restart the RDS instance too, but didn't get the solution.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Hi, check the src image its trying to load. Check the browser console for any errors

Comment: Do you store the images on the instance? Also can there be any process or some configuration which would remove or move images after at the boot time?

Comment: You'll need to debug the situation. Look at the URL for the images. What does it look like? It is possible that they are going to a previous IP address that was assigned to the Amazon EC2 instance, but the IP address changed when the instance was stopped and started. As for the slowness, you could do a test by changing the EC2 instance to a **larger instance type**. You'll need to stop the instance, change its instance type, then start the instance.  Larger instances have more memory and CPU. See whether that makes things go faster.

Comment: @Marcin I have uploaded the images to the wordpress site from my local machine. And these are uploaded automatically to the wp-content directory of the instance (I can see it). I dont think there is any process which remove images after reboot. Because now also  i can see the images present on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.
Actually the main problem was of the location of the pictures, I uploaded it from my local machine. This is what i think. 
Solution- I copied the /var/www/html/uploads directory to S3 bucket.
And used the cloudfront CDN of AWS and used the source as the s3 bucket.
Now its working fine for me. Even after stopping the instance and restarting it, the site is getting up quickkly.

Thanks.